# The OSX function `kCGWindowWorkspace` is deprecated. Any workarounds? How *now* to determine which Desktop Workspace any given window is in?

Tags: macos, api, desktop, workspace

It seems that from OSX 10.5 to OSX 10.8, Apple provided an API,`kCGWindowWorkspace, that would tell you what Mission Control Desktop Workspace any particular window was in.

But no longer.

Is there any way to do it in Mojove, Catalina, or more recent versions?

If I manually activate a particular window, I will move to that MC Desktop Space; I can then query to find which space that is. But I would like to, for instance, generate a list of all open TextEdit windows together with which Deskstop Workspace they are in, without having to move to each Workspace in turn.

This kind of information is valuable to me because I'm currently working with 21 open Desktop Workspaces, several personal projects, work projects, personal finances, research, various recreations, etc. I'm probably not the only one.

Comment: I found someone on github with the same problem... their suggestion isn't pretty: https://github.com/bigbearlabs/MotionKit/blob/5219b2b7a2ff49ca62c7dfce43353aca5be914eb/lib/motion-kit/ui/osx/spaces.rb _"since mountain lion we can't reliably obtain space id's from the window list's kCGWindowWorkspace property. a possible way to work around is to drop an anchor window on every new space, and let the anchor window id stand in for the space id."_

Comment: Yes, is the method of the one app that I know of that continues to function in Mojave and Catalina, CurrentKey. It's free, but it's been withdrawn because he can't support Monterey. Other people have created homebrewed workarounds by using Stickies on every Desktop Workspace.

Comment: Welcome to post-iPod Apple, summarized as "No _real_ UX personalization allowed" - it's quite a contrast to the Apple of the late 1990s that [expressly supported entire custom themes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appearance_Manager)... It's amazing how much we can get done thanks to ObjectiveC function swizzling, but as Apple moves more things over to Swift (which doesn't use reflection and named message passing) what little we can still do today will drop down to naught...

Comment: In Spencer Dailey's Current Key, he puts an "invisible" app on each window, where the title of the window is the name of the desktop space, and by activating the appropriate window he triggers the change of Desktop Workspaces. Using Stickies on each Desktop lets you switch desktops by clicking on the current Sticky Note, then using the Window dropdown to see the list. Either way allows you to give each window a meaningful name instead of an arbitrary number (which changes if you change the order of the desktops in Mission Control). Some form of this seems to be the state of the art.

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub utility WhichSpace <github.com/gechr/WhichSpace> will put a numeric icon in the toolbar, indicating which Desktop number is the current Space.

This can be queried with Applescript to put that number into a variable:

```
    tell application "System Events" to tell process ¬
        "WhichSpace" to set mySpaceNumberCurrent ¬
        to (title of menu bar items of menu bar 1)
```

The following Swift code will call a function when the Desktop changes. That's also potentially useful:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(forName: NSWorkspace.activeSpaceDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil, using: <the function you want to handle this event> )
```

This does *not, yet* answer the original question, to determine the Desktop Workspace of a given window. But it's a start in that direction.

I am using the above two tools to develop macros using Keyboard Maestro that hopefully will eventually answer the original question. Progress is discussed [on the KBM user forum here](https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/switch-to-previous-desktop-space/25869).